# Code Analysis CA2000: Is this code okay?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, dispose

Have a look at this code, I believe it solved CA2000 but I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something. Basically this code loads a new `Control` based on what is selected in a `TreeView`. That `Control` is then displayed and is visible/usable until another `Node` in the `TreeView` is selected.

```
private void Something(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    ProjectTreeNode node = (e.Node as ProjectTreeNode);

    foreach (Control c in optionsPlaceholderPanel.Controls)
        c.Dispose();

    optionsPlaceholderPanel.Controls.Clear();

    if (node != null)
    {
        //ProjectOptions inherits from Control and is therefore IDisposable
        ProjectOptions options = new ProjectOptions(node.Project);

        ShowOptionsPanel(options);
    }
}

private void ShowOptionsPanel(Control control)
{
    optionsPlaceholderPanel.Controls.Add(control);
    control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

So basically the `Control` is in scope always, until a new `Control` is loaded in place of it. When I do that, I'm disposing the prior-loaded `Control` so I think it's safe to ignore CA2000 in this case. Also, when the `Form` finally closes and `optionsPlaceholderPanel` is disposed, this will also dispose the child controls, right?

Comment: And if node is null the old Control will remain visible?

Comment: Right - that won't actually "ever" happen, just a precaution. Basically when a node is clicked I will load a specific "options panel" to edit that node. This may or may not always be a ProjectOptions control.

Comment: @extraneon - Actually there's no reason to not move the dispose code to occur before the new control is instantiated - updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (Control c in optionsPlaceholderPanel.Controls)
    c.Dispose();
```

No, this code has a bug.  Which in itself is triggered by a bug in the ControlCollection class.  Your foreach loop is *modifying* the panel's Controls collection.  This normally produces an InvalidOperationException, "Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute", but the class forgets to do this.

The Dispose() call on the control removes it from the collection.  In effect, you'll only dispose every other control.  This should have a side-effect, they remain visible on the panel.  Ymmv.  Fix:

```
        for (int ix = optionsPlaceholderPanel.Controls.Count - 1; ix >= 0; --ix)
            optionsPlaceholderPanel.Controls[ix].Dispose();
```

Or less efficient, although you'd never see the difference:

```
        while (optionsPlaceholderPanel.Controls.Count > 0)
             optionsPlaceholderPanel.Controls[0].Dispose();
```

Otherwise the code is okay, CA2000 tends to produce false warnings.

Comment: Yeah good point about the "collection was modified" error. I hate that error! Thanks, I just wanted to be sure it was okay to ignore this warning. I'll make the edits you've suggested. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, Microsoft should have explicitly allowed for IEnumerables to either throw an exception on modification or permit certain types of modifications during enumeration if they could uphold certain requirements (e.g. enumerating every unmodified item exactly once), and had two derived interfaces, one of which would mandate the former behavior and one of which would mandate the latter; IEnumerable implementations would be encouraged to implement one of the latter interfaces.  Being able to delete items from a collection while enumerating really is useful, when it works.

Comment: No, it is always wrong.  There's no way to tell from the IEnumerable instance that it might work.  And it never does, just delete an entry and add it back.  It gets enumerated twice, usually.